# Relogin on a page even if another tab is opened with variables session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I implement this behavior in my website
I need to be logged inside my website to navigate through the website and if I open a new tab, I want to display the login page, also the user logged on the previous tab doesn't have to be logged on the new one.(treat all new tabs like independent session)

when the user is logged a security token is stored on my Session[token], if I open another tab, another user can be logged into the website with another token session.(this has to be don't in the same browser)

Comment: Cookies are shared between browser tabs so this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that but each has some limitation. All ways required some short of custom development on client side and server side to manage the data.

1. Don't use cookie or traditional authentication mechanism as all has cookie per domain so it wan't help.
2. If you are using HTML5 then you can take advantage of sessionStorage and store different Id ( generate guid) and pass along with each request to identify. ( More secure you have to generate your own encrypted value)
3. For simple use you can use HiddenField on each tab and get value from Url.
4. If you are aware of ASP.net cookieless session then you can see that url has sessionid and you have to do something similar.
5. In MVC you can do such thing by creating custom route.
   http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/02/get-a-unique-session-in-each-browser-tab/